# How do I encode/decode a dictionary in Python 3 to/from an external file?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, python-3.x, encode

I'm relatively new to and encoding and decoding, in fact I don't have any experience with it at all.

I was wondering, how would I decode a dictionary in Python 3 into an unreadable format that would prevent someone from modifying it outside the program?
Likewise, how would I then read from that file and encode the dictionary back?

My test code right now only writes to and reads from a plain text file.

```
import ast

myDict = {}

#Writer
fileModifier = open('file.txt', 'w')
fileModifier.write(str(myDict)))
fileModifier.close()

#Reader
fileModifier = open('file.txt', 'r')
myDict = ast.literal_eval(fileModifier.read())
fileModifier.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your dictionary is holding you can use an encoding library like [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) (useful for storing my complex python data structures).

Here is an example using json, to use pickle just replace all instances of `json` with `pickle` and you should be good to go.

```
import json

myDict = {}

#Writer
fileModifier = open('file.txt', 'w'):
json.dump(myDict, fileModifier)
fileModifier.close()

#Reader
fileModifier = open('file.txt', 'r'):
myDict = json.load(fileModifier)
fileModifier.close()
```

Comment: This does the exact same thing as my code though. I need it to decode the dictionary into an unreadable format that would prevent someone from modifying it outside the program. I'll update my OP to be more clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

The typical thing to use here is either the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) modules (both in the standard library).  The process is called "serialization".  `pickle` can serialize *almost* arbitrary python objects whereas `json` can only serialize basic types/objects (integers, floats, strings, lists, dictionaries).  `json` is human readible at the end of the day whereas `pickle` files aren't.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to encoding/decoding is to simply use a file as a `dict`, and python has the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module which does exactly this. This module uses a file as database and provide a `dict`-like interface to it.

It has some limitations, for example keys must be strings, and it's obviously slower than a normal `dict` since it performs I/O operations.